# Cython & tox - ModuleNotFoundError on 3.9, but not 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, setuptools, tox

I'm converting some of my scripts in my package to cython to try and speed up execution time, and I'm having some trouble getting it to work with tox.

The tests are passing on 3.8, but on 3.9 I get the error:

```
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.subpackage.module'
```

Upon investigating the `build` folder, the 3.9 build has both `module_cpython-38-darwin.so` and `module_cpython-39-darwin.so` (whereas the 3.8 build only has the 3.8 .so file). Manually deleting the 3.8 .so file doesn't change anything, but it's still strange that its included in one and not the other.

This is my project structure:

```
Project
|
|-pyproject.toml
|-setup.py
|-setup.cfg
|-MANIFEST.in
|-tox.ini
|
|-src
| |
| |-package
|   |
|   |-subpackage
|     |-module.c
|     |-module_cpython-38-darwin.so
|     |-module.pyx
|
|-tests
| |-test_package.py
```

What I've done so far to accomodate cython is add the following to `pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg`, `setup.py`, and `MANIFEST.IN`

```
# pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "setuptools_scm[toml]>=3.4", "cython"]
```

```
# setup.cfg
[options]

setup_requires =
    setuptools_scm
    cython
```

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension('package.subpackage.module', sources=['./src/package/subpackage/module.pyx'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(use_scm_version=True, ext_modules=cythonize([ext]))
```

```
# MANIFEST.in

global-include *.so
```

I'm not sure if `.so` files should be included in the manifest - but removing them from the manifest doesn't change anything.

Any idea why it's not working? Have I done something wrong with my project config?

Thanks.

Comment: It probably isn't the build folder that it's getting imported from. It might be worth printing the module's `__file__` attribute or starting Python with the verbose flag to see where it is coming from

Comment: @DavidW I think you're right. The tests fail for py38 when the .c and .so files aren't in the `src` folder, and pass when they are. So I need to figure out how to configure `tox` to import from the correct directory.